# Finding a specific number whose divisors exceed a fixed value.

Tags: divisor-sum

I am trying to find smallest number s.t. it's square has more than 8 million divisors. It might seem impossible for hand and even while solving with a computer, it requires great amount of time (but I have been able to establish that the number is greater than 2147483647 till now). I have also plotted some graphs and I think there is some pattern in the numbers which have large number of divisors nad it seems like they occur on periodic distances:
[(Note: $\sigma_x(n)$ is Divisor Function)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)

[image]

$$y=\sigma_0(x^2)$$
What could be a possible approach to finding that number, if required using a computer too.

We notice that we need to find:
$$N=\prod^n p_i^{q_i}$$
where:
$$\prod^n(2q_i+1)>8\times10^6$$
while minimizing N.

Comment: why 8 million??

Comment: @WillJagy this problem stems from finding an efficient way to finding n (therefore large number : 8 million) s.t. 1/x+1/y=1/n has more than 4 million solution

Comment: Was that No. 108 or 110?

Comment: @DanielFischer ispun intended?

Comment: I didn't remember which number the problem had.

Comment: @DanielFischer 110. You also do these?

Comment: A loooooooong time ago.

Comment: @DanielFischer how many did you did?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 
the arbitrary use of  8 million makes the question
ridiculous. Why 8 million?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to exhibit such a number, for example $2^{8000000}$ is the square of $2^{4000000}$. But perhaps you want the smallest number in which case the number of divisors of $N=\prod p_i^{a_i}$ where the $p_i$ are distinct primes is $\prod (a_i+1)$. You need all the $a_i$ to be even. If you choose  $a_i=2$ note that $3^{15}\gt 8000000$  so you will need fifteen primes. Or $3^{6}\times 5^6\gt 8000000$ with twelve primes.

So using this analysis you can search for the least square with more than $8000000$ divisors. It is easy to make this a finite search.